# how to pupoulate radio buttons and display this form

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am using materialize framework and i have to populate this form using java script. I am not sure how to access them in my js file

```
<div class="row col s10 offset-s1" id="questionArea" style="display:none">
      <blockquote class="flow-text"> Select the capital of the country shown below.</blockquote>
     <div class="input-field col s6">
       Question <span id="quesTextSpan"></span><p>
         <input name="qOptions" type="radio" id="optionId0" class="with-gap qOptionClass" />
         <label for="optionId0"></label>
       </p>
       <p>
         <input name="qOptions" type="radio" id="optionId1" class="with-gap qOptionClass" />
         <label for="optionId1"></label>
       </p>
       <p>
         <input  name="qOptions" type="radio" id="optionId2" class="with-gap qOptionClass" />
         <label for="optionId2">d</label>
       </p>
       <p>
         <input  name="qOptions" type="radio" id="optionId3" class="with-gap qOptionClass" />
         <label for="optionId3"></label>
       </p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the values of the radio buttons like this:

```
var radioVal = document.getElementById('optionId0').checked;
```

You can then perform logic on them by using conditionals and functions.

To gather them all quickly I would recommend doing this.

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
```

This will give you an array with each of the elements.
You may then go through and change the value to true or false depending on how you want to populate them.

Example)

```
radios[0].checked = true // Sets the first radio button to be on.
```

Edit)

To display the div use:

```
document.getElementById('questionArea').style.display = '';
```

To hide the div use:

```
document.getElementById('questionArea').style.display = 'hidden';
```

Comment: can you help me in displaying it?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tesenowovi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Reason for downvote?